# Processing 100 MB+ files from FTP server in less than 30 sec?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency, ftp

**Problem Statement:**  FTP server is flooded with files coming at the rate of 100 Mbps(ie. 12.5 MB/s) each file size is 100 MB approx. Files will be deleted after 30 sec from their creation time stamp. If any process is interested to read those files it should take away complete file in less then 30 sec. I am using Java to solve this particular problem.

**Need suggestion on** which Design pattern would be best suited for this kind of problem. How would I make sure that the each file will be consumed before server delete it.

*Your suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks*

Comment: Writing code for that problem statement is not a matter of _design patterns_. If any, it is a matter of efficient IO operations. "How would I make sure that the each file will be consumed before server delete it?" => Honestly. You can't. There are so many things that could go wrong. Would you like to make it failure-proof? What about, if nearly all bytes are read - but not all - and then the file disappears? Can it even disappear if some other process has a handle on it? Really, this questions is far too broad.

Comment: The other processes should put a lock on the file when accessing it, so it prevents it from being deleted by the server I suppose.

Comment: @KevynMeganck   Yes putting lock is possible and helpful in this scenario. Thanks

Comment: @KevynMeganck If you can find a lock implementation that prevents deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Java application runs on the same machine as the FTP service, then it could use `File.renameTo(File)` or equivalent to move a required file out of the FTP server directory and into another directory.  Then it can process it at its leisure.  It could use a `WatchService` to monitor the FTP directory for newly arrived files.  It should watch for events on the directory, and when a file starts to appear it should wait for the writes to stop happening.  (Depending on the OS, you may or may not be able to move the file while the FTP service is writing to it.)

There is a secondary issue of whether a Java application could keep up with the required processing rate.  However, if you had multiple cores and multiple worker threads, then your app could potentially process them in parallel.  (It depends on computationally and/or I/O intensive the processing is.  And the rate at which a Java thread can read a file ... which will be OS and possibly hardware dependent.)

If the Java application is not running on the FTP server, it would probably need to use FTP to fetch the file.  I am doubtful that you could implement something to do that consistently and reliably; i.e. without losing files occasionally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "If the Java application runs on the same machine as the FTP service, then it could use File.renameTo(File) or equivalent to move a required file out of the FTP server directory and into another directory" --> Java application will be connecting remotely to the FTP server.

Comment: Then see the last paragraph.